# Android: How to get 3rd party view size

Tags: android, android-layout

I wish to get size of 3rd party banner that I can't override to add `onMeasure` or `onSizeChanged` methods. Is there way to get banner size or at least height.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html):

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // Check the width and height here
  }
});
```